# Is there a way to improve copying to the clipboard format from Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When using Bash on Windows, copying from the terminal results in terribly formatted content when I paste. Here is a `curl` request I made and copied directly from Bash on Ubuntu on Windows:

```
$ curl -IL aol.com                                                                                                                                                                                                              HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently                                                                                                                                                                                                               Date: Fri, 27 Apr 2018 15:58:31 GMT                                                                                                                                                                                                          Server: Apache                                                                                                                                                                                                                               Location: https://www.aol.com/                                                                                                                                                                                                               Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

It's basically all on one line, almost like the carriage returns are not respected. I would expect the paste output to look like this:

```
$ curl -IL aol.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 27 Apr 2018 15:19:49 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.aol.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Is there a way to fix this? Right now I have to go into a text editor to format every copy/paste I need to make.

Edit: Here is a screen shot of the above code blocked copied to the clipboard directly from Bash on Win10: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl6aO.png

Comment: Looks like something is missing in the question.

Comment: I'm asking if there is a formatting setting or anything that can be done so that when I copy a block of text from BoUoW, it pastes as a block and not one line. Edit: I see what you meant. Fixing.

Comment: WSL is just using the normal Windows 10 console, and copying from it works no different than any other console application. I ran this `curl -IL aol.com` command and pasted the output into Notepad and Notepad++, and it pasted without error. Revealing the line endings in Notepad++ shows that the lines end with CRLF, as one would expect with text copied from the console.

Comment: It's probably worth revising the title to more clearly refer to copying to the clipboard from the terminal, vs. referring to, say, files copied with `cp` or `copy`.

Comment: @eryksun Here is a screenshot of what it looks like when I past to Notepad++: https://i.imgur.com/VUKRhLX.png.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong that would produce a paste like that. Even the "curl -IL aol.com" command got split on two lines. In the View->Show Symbol menu of Notepad++, select "show all characters" and take another screen shot.

Comment: @eryksun here is the screenshot requested: https://i.imgur.com/bpNLXRS.png . Would it be possible to get a screenshot of your bash settings window? Maybe I have something borked there.

Comment: If you have Python 3 and PyWin32 installed, the following will print the exact contents of the clipboard: `python -c "import win32clipboard; win32clipboard.OpenClipboard(); print(ascii(win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()))"`. The `ascii` function renders non-printable characters as escapes, e.g. for the text copied from the console on my test system, it shows CRLF line endings as `\r\n`, and there's no spaces at the end of the lines.

Comment: I just ran this command in Bash on Ubuntu in WSL/Windows and copy pasted into Notepad++ with no problems. Came out with proper Window s CRLF line endings. Are you in the legacy console? Are the settings of the console still default (I've toggled a few of the settings related to clipboard but was still unable to reproduce this).

Comment: @JNevill I am not on Legacy and all settings are default. I just switched on Legacy and now it won't open at all. I'm going to look into re-installing.

Comment: Reinstalled, but no resolution.